# How to disable automatic switching to sleep mode in Linux Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, sleep-mode

By default it automatically goes to sleep mode after some time. How to switch that off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open **Settings** -> **Power** and the last configuration option is **Suspend & Power Off**. Clicking on the option below it, you will be able to configure when it will go to sleep or not **On Battery** and when **Plugged In** (Gnome shell):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this class of setting can be found in the power management tool, but where that is can vary between desktop environments